# Let $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow S^1 \times S^1$ given by $f(t)=(\cos(\sqrt{2}t),\sin(\sqrt{2}t),\cos(t),\sin(t))$ show that $f$ is a injective inmersion

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

> Let $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow S^1 \times S^1$ given by $f(t)=(\cos(\sqrt{2}t),\sin(\sqrt{2}t),\cos(t),\sin(t))$ show that $f$ is a injective inmersion in $S^1 \times S^1$ and that $f(\mathbb{R})$ is dense in $S^1 \times S^1$

First note that $f(t)=(G(t),H(t))$ with $G:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow S^1$ define by $ G(t)=(\cos(\sqrt{2}t),\sin(\sqrt{2}t))$ and $H:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow S^1$ define by $H(t)=(\cos(t),\sin(t))$ i know that $F$ and $H$ are inmersions then $f$ is a inmersion from $\mathbb{R}$ to $S^1 \times S^1$ is these correct?

Now for the injectivity i have problems i try to use the identification of $\mathbb{R}/ \sim$ with $S^1$ given by $t \sim t + \mathbb{Z}$ but i not sure to these is correct

And i try to use the fact that $\{\sqrt{2}n+m\}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ but i dont know how conclude the problem.
Any hint or help i will be very grateful.

Answer (score 4):

For injectivity:

If $f(s)=f(t)$ then $\cos(t) = \cos(s)$ and $\sin(t) = \sin(s)$ which means that $t = s + 2\pi k$ for some integer $k$. Similarly, from $\cos(\sqrt2\ t) = \cos(\sqrt2\ s)$ and $\sin(\sqrt2\ t) = \sin(\sqrt2\ s)$ we have that $\sqrt2\ t = \sqrt2\ s + 2\pi l$ for some integer $l$. Then $s + 2\pi k = t = s + \sqrt 2\ \pi l$, so $\sqrt 2\ k = l$. This can only happen when $k=l=0$ so $t=s$.

Comment: A "shorter" (but equivalent) way: $f$ is a group homomorphism, so it suffices to check its kernel (with your technique for example)

Comment: that´s  nice, thank you¡ for the density is a good strategy try using sequence and the density of $\{ n+\sqrt{2}m; n,m \in \mathbb{Z}\}$? @Didier

Comment: @Winter_Spartan Yes it is